# googletest printing COleDateTime values

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I have integrated googletest into our MFC application. However while writing tests involving COleDateTime objects I came across the following warning:

```
1>gtest/gtest-printers.h(169) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'DATE' to 'const testing::internal::BiggestInt', possible loss of data
1>gtest/gtest-printers.h(168) : while compiling class template member function 'void testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<T,kTypeKind>::PrintValue(const T &,std::ostream *)'
```

The test was the following:

```
TEST(FunctionTest, SumDays) 
{
    COleDateTime res = SumDays(COleDateTime(2010,10,31,0,0,0), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(COleDateTime(2010,11,01,0,0,0), res);
}
```

The problem is I cannot add a << operator or a PrintTo method as the documentation announces.
Allot more tests are going to involve date values so I want to avoid the inline solution the documentation refers to.

**Is there a good solution to control the print string for COleDateTime values?**

The current output comes out like:

```
<failure message="Value of: res&#x0A;  Actual: 40512&#x0A;Expected: COleDateTime(2010,10,30,0,0,0)&#x0A;Which is: 40481" type=""><![CDATA[.\Code.cpp:6837
Value of: res
  Actual: 40512
Expected: COleDateTime(2010,10,30,0,0,0)
Which is: 40481]]></failure>
```

Notice the **Actual** value!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same porblem and figured out, that - in contrast to [Caerbanogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623063/googletest-printing-coledatetime-values#comment7845971_6630242) statement - implementing the `PrintTo`-Function(s) helps indeed. One important thing is to make sure that the Class for that one "extends" a behaviour for googletest has **exactly the same namespace** as the `PrintTo`-Function.

In this case that is the namespace `ATL`!

This leads to the following solution for `COleDateTime` and `COleDateTimeSpan`:

```
namespace ATL {

    void PrintTo(const COleDateTime& dtDatum, ::std::ostream* os)
    {
        // I want an additional Format, so I append a human readable notion
        *os << dtDatum.m_dt << " (" << (LPCSTR)dtDatum.Format(_T("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")) << ")";
    }

    void PrintTo(const COleDateTimeSpan& dsSpanne, ::std::ostream* os)
    {
        *os << dsSpanne.m_span;
    }

}
```

Just put that into a place, which you can include from all your googletest-Projects (if you have more than one).

At last it works for me :-)